# i have an option derivative question

Tags: derivatives, calculation

[image]

please show that the call and the put share the same vega, i.e., please prove the following equality.

do we derive the call and put equations ?

Comment: The screenshot is bad, we barely see the questions

Answer (score 4):

Use the call put parity :

$$C(t,F_{t,T},T,\sigma,K)-P(t,F_{t,T},T,\sigma,K)=F_{t,T}-K$$ where $F_{t,T}$ is the forward rate(underlying), $K$ is the strike, $t$ the valuation date, $\sigma$ the model volatility, $T$ is the maturity.

Differentiate the equation with respect to $\sigma$, and you will get the result wanted.

Comment: but if we want to do it directly how would we go on about it

Comment: The proof is model independent. Take any model, if the call/ put price have a closed-form formula, then derive it and you will get the same results.

Comment: I am not sure the proof is model independent. The *put-call parity* is definitely model independent; however, the above result regarding volatility relies on assuming that cross partial derivatives of input parameters are zero, which I feel is model dependent. (i.e. You can have models where cross partial derivatives are non-zero)

Comment: You mean there are cases when $\frac{\partial (F_{t,T}-K)}{\partial \sigma} \ne 0$ ?

Comment: @canardini yes - take for example a model where dividends payout unless you're below some value, now your forward is short vol.